# Bluetooth Low Energy Notification Characteristics

Tags: notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, characteristics, bluetooth-gatt

I just want to figure out. If i have the BLE(cc2541) and android APP. BLE has characteristics for notification, read, write and other. Can i write value to notification characteristics from BLE, read it with android APP, and then write to same notification characteristics from android APP to BLE?

Comment: by the same i mean using the same UUID

Answer (score 0):

It all depends  on the firmware in the device.

I have a cc2541 with jnhuamao firmware and get notifications and read and write to the device with the same characteristic.

The service has Uuid  0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb called SimpleKeyService

The characteristic has Uuid 0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb with the properties Read, WriteWithoutResponse and Notify.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot.

Comment: Is there a source code or example - how to do that(use the same characteristic for read write and notify)? I mean a source code for cc2541 or another BLE.